# Setup git repository on gentoo server using gitosis & ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, git, gentoo

I installed git and gitosis as described here in [this guide](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)  Here are the steps I took:

Server: **Gentoo**
Client: **MAC OS X**

1)  git install

```
emerge dev-util/git
```

2) gitosis install

```
cd ~/src
git clone git://eagain.net/gitosis.git
cd gitosis
python setup.py install
```

3) added **git** user

```
adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --comment 'git version control' --no-user-group --home-dir /home/git git
```

In `/etc/shadow` now:

```
git:!:14665::::::
```

4) On local computer (Mac OS X) (local login is **ipx**, server login is **expert**)

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

got 2 files:

```
~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

5) Copied `id_dsa.pub` onto server

```
~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

Added content from file `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` into file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub /tmp/id_dsa.pub
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```

6) Added 2 params to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Full `sshd_config`:

```
Protocol 2
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
Subsystem   sftp   /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server
```

7) Local settings in file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver.com.ua
User expert
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

8) Tested:

```
ssh expert@myserver.com.ua
```

Done!

9) Next step. There I have problem

```
git clone git@myserver.com.ua:gitosis-admin.git
cd gitosis-admin
```

SSH asked password for user **git**. Why ssh should allow me to login as user **git**?  The **git** user doesn't have a password. The ssh key I created is for the user **expert**. How this should work?

Do I have to add some params to `sshd_config`?

Answer (score 3):

As a notice for anybody who finds this question in the future, I would like to point out that gitosis has been declared as deprecated by the majority of the git community and appears to be abandoned by its author.

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite#start) has become its successor and is unanimously agreed to be superior in every way, most importantly being ease of use, troubleshooting, and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed a couple steps from the guide.  After setting up the ssh keys it says:

> Next we will run a command that will
>   sprinkle some magic into the home
>   directory of the git user and put your
>   public SSH key into the list of
>   authorized keys.
>
> ```
> sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
> ```

and...

> For good measure, let's make sure the
>   post-update hook is set executable.
>   I've seen it where sometimes it
>   doesn't get set (problem with older
>   setuptools):
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
> ```

then you want to do the step you were having trouble with:

```
git clone git@YOUR_SERVER_HOSTNAME:gitosis-admin.git
cd gitosis-admin
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did this on step 5
`sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update`

But ssh asked a password...

Answer (score 0):

On step 5, you don't need to add the key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file yourself... the gitosis-init does that for you.

And on your client side, in the ~/.ssh/config file the settings should be:

```
Host myserver.com.ua
User git
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

since you want the password-less login to happen for the git user on the server.